# When does the blacksmith restock?

Tags: sanctuary-rpg

I was an idiot and said, "No thanks, I don't want that godly weapon you have yet. Let me see what else you have." and the blacksmith responded, "Oh, you don't want it? Let me melt it down *immediately* then so no one can ever have it again."

Now he doesn't have anything for sale. What will cause the blacksmith to have more weapons for me to look through?

Comment: It seems to fully restock on Level Up, and partially restock other times, possibly gaining of Soul Shard?

Answer (score -1):

Blacksmith restocks after a few battles I think.